# If you're using a generic DataGrid, is there a way to hide specific fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I've got some code like this:

## asp.net

```
<div id="divGrid" style='width:920px; height:430px; overflow:auto'>
    <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid_AuditSearch" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
    OnCancelCommand="DataGrid_AuditSearch_CancelCommand" 
    OnUpdateCommand="DataGrid_AuditSearch_UpdateCommand" 
    OnEditCommand="DataGrid_AuditSearch_EditCommand">
        <AlternatingItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <EditItemStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" 
           Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:EditCommandColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CancelText="Cancel" 
               EditText="Select" UpdateText="Update"></asp:EditCommandColumn>
        </Columns>

    </asp:DataGrid>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="font-weight:bold; font-size:large;"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

## C#:

```
public void Show_Data(int AuditID)
{
    try
    {
        OracleConnection conn = GetConnection();
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnCST"].ToString();

            OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand();
            cmd3.Connection = conn;

            sqlquery2 = "SELECT * from MyTable";

            cmd3.CommandText = sqlquery2;

            var SearchAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd3);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            SearchAdapter.Fill(ds);

            // Perform the binding.
            DataGrid_AuditSearch.DataSource = ds;
            DataGrid_AuditSearch.DataBind();

            if (DataGrid_AuditSearch.Items.Count < 1)
            {
                lblEmpty.Visible = true;
                lblEmpty.Text = "There is no data to display";
            }
            else
            {
                lblEmpty.Visible = false;
            }

            //DataGrid_AuditSearch.Columns[3].Visible = false;
            //DataGrid_AuditSearch.Columns[1].Visible = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Pretty boring, generic stuff.  All fields are generated based on the binding.

However, there are 2 fields I want to be able to access (because I need the data), but I don't want to show on the screen.  Is there a way to do this "dynamically"?  In that, I don't want to have to explicitly name all the fields I want to display and in what order.

I tried adding this after the DataBind command, but it didn't do anything:

```
DataGrid_AuditSearch.Columns[3].Visible = false;
DataGrid_AuditSearch.Columns[1].Visible = false;
```

Comment: You don't have any columns to hide except for an EditCommandColumn, which would be DataGrid_AuditSearch.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Comment: Well, that's not true.  7 fields are displayed when I run that code.  The EditCommandColumn is a button, and the grid also has 6 fields brought in from the data adapter.  And **yes**, that's all the code I use to fill it.

Comment: Show the code that creates the columns.

Comment: **That's all the code**.  Pop it in a C# app and test it yourself.  I've *never* specified columns in a datagrid.  Well, once when I was using a Net Advantage tool, but never when using a VS datagrid.

Comment: OK, I edited it.  And that's LITERALLY it.  It's called on Page_Load.

Comment: You don't define sqlquery2 anywhere.

Comment: Well, I've got a datagrid full of data so that isn't the problem.  If that was an issue, the code would stop running at sqlquery2 = "SELECT * from MyTable";

Answer (score 0):

Automatically generated columns are not added to the Columns collection therefore they are not available to set properties on.  A better approach is to create the columns declaratively and access them in the PreRender or Load events of the DataGrid.  (I did run your code and test for myself).

Here is a great article on creating DataGrid columns:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx